# awk runs but resulting output is empty

Tags: awk

The `awk` below runs, however the output file is 0 bytes. It is basically matching input files that are 21 - 259 records to a file of 11,137,660 records. Basically, what it does is use the input files of which there are 4 to search and match in a large 11,000,000 record file and output the average of all the `$7` in the matches. I can not seem to figure out why the file is empty. Thank you :).

**input**

```
AGRN
CCDC39 
CCDC40 
CFTR
```

**search**

```
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543 AGRN-6|gc=75    1   0
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543 AGRN-6|gc=75    2   2
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543 AGRN-6|gc=75    3   2
```

**expected output**

```
chr1:955543 AGRN|gc=75 1.3
```

**awk**

```
 awk '
 NR == FNR {input[$0]; next}
 {
    split($5, a, "-")
    if (a[1] in input) {
         key = $4 OFS $5
         n[key]++
         sum[key] += $7
     }
 }
 END {
     for (key in n) 
         printf "%s %.1f\n", key, sum[key]/n[key]
 }
' search.txt input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: looks very close to done. Try adding some debugging statements. `print "#dbg:sum["key"]"="sum[key]...` . Good luck.

Comment: You seem to have `awk '…' search.txt input.txt`; don't you need the files in the reverse order: `awk '…' input.txt search.txt` (at least if the tagging against the information in the question is correct).

Comment: Edit your question to show the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the search file comes first in ARGV, you can't do the data matchup until END [as `input` will be empty].

Here's what I think will work.  Based upon your test files, it produces a single line of output:

```
chr1:955543 AGRN-6|gc=75 0.7
```

Here is the script file, invoked with `awk -f script.awk search.txt input.txt`:

```
BEGIN {
    slen = 0;
}

# get input file(s)
# NOTE: IMO, this is a cleaner better test condition
ARGIND > 1 {
    ###printf("input_push: DEBUG %s\n",$0);
    input[$0];
    next;
}

# get single search list
{
    ###printf("search_push: DEBUG %s\n",$0);
    search[slen++] = $0;
    next;
}

END {
    # sum up data
    for (sidx = 0;  sidx < slen;  ++sidx) {
        sval = search[sidx];
        ###printf("search_end: DEBUG %s\n",sval);

        split(sval,sary)
        split(sary[5],a,"-");
        ###printf("search_end: DEBUG sary[5]='%s' a[1]='%s'\n",sary[5],a[1]);

        if (a[1] in input) {
            key = sary[4] OFS sary[5]
            n[key]++
            sum[key] += sary[7]
        }
    }

    for (key in n)
        printf "%s %.1f\n", key, sum[key]/n[key]
}
```

Comment: `FNR == NR` while processing the first file (`search.txt`) but not when processing subsequent files (`input.txt`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler As you say, it may/probably works, but, IMO, `ARGIND` is more direct, more general, and closer to intent.  If there were three or more file "types", we'd probably need (e.g.) `ARGIND == 1 { foo[$0]; next } ARGIND == 2 { bar[$0]; next } ARGIND == 3 { baz[$0]; next }`.  The rest about the ordering still holds unless OP [with multiple input files] wants to put the search.txt as the last. I'll edit my answer accordingly

Comment: I'm not debating your use of ARGIND.  I'm debating the accuracy of your opening sentence: _I believe `NR == FNR` is always true._  That statement is inaccurate; as I said, `NR == FNR` is only true while reading the first file.  You might usefully note that ARGIND is a feature of GNU [Awk](https://gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Built_002din-Variables), not POSIX [Awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Removed the opening.  As to awk type/ver, gawk [as it was called/installed] has been around for 20+.  IMO, it's time to standardize on best superset. (e.g.) bash [non-proprietary and universal] is [arguably] that, yet people still want/defend sh solutions. The benefit of (t)csh [before bash] was universality, whereas sh could be various incompatible flavors. linux/cygwin/BSD(?) use gawk, so where's non-gawk these days? I used to do csh/sed/awk/grep [100,000 lines], but switched 100% to perl [in 1991] as I realized it could replace it all with better results [python good too]

Comment: shouldn't the last field be 1.3.  Thank you :)

Comment: @CraigEstey: Debian-based distributions such as Ubuntu come with Mawk, not Gawk. BSD platforms and OS X come with BWK Awk, not Gawk. Therefore, it's still worth noting when Gawk-specific features are used.

Comment: Yes--my bad. I was mostly concerned with fixing the "no output" problem.  I didn't cut-n-paste your summation logic, I reentered it by hand.  When I did so, I ended up with `sum[key] = sary[7]` instead of `sum[key] += sary[7]`.  I was reentering because I was looking over the logic as I did so, looking for a no-output related bug, and, ironically, I introduced the summation one. I've tweaked the code and it now produces 1.3